# finding solution to a partial integro differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, integral-equations, integral-transforms, integro-differential-equations

I want to find a function (or a set of functions) such that  $u(x,t)$ satisfies the following partial integro-differential equation with singular kernel
\begin{eqnarray}
&&u_x(0,t) = \int_0^t \frac{u_\lambda(0,\lambda)}{\sqrt{t-\lambda}} d\lambda, \\ 
&&u(0,0) = 0.
\end{eqnarray}
I tried the Laplace transform method but i couldn't find the solution.
Some help would be greatly appreciated.